# Creating JMS Queue with JMX on WebSphere

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jmx

I want to create a JMS Queue with Scope:Cluster.

```
Session session = new Session();
ConfigService cService = new ConfigServiceProxy(aClient);

queryString = "Cluster=xxx";
ObjectName temp = cService.resolve(session, queryString)[0];

CommandMgr cmdMgr = CommandMgr.getCommandMgr(aClient);

    AdminCommand cmd = cmdMgr.createCommand("createSIBJMSQueue");
    cmd.setTargetObject(obj);

    cmd.setParameter("name", Name);
    cmd.setParameter("jndiName", "jms/"+Name);
    cmd.setParameter("description", "FirstTryOfJMX");
    cmd.setParameter("busName", "bus");
    cmd.setParameter("queueName", "was");

    cmd.setConfigSession(session);

    cmd.execute();

    CommandResult result = cmd.getCommandResult();
```

This Example works very well if i choose other scopes like -> Node="xxx":Server="xxx".
I think the problem is the resolve() function from WebSphere: I find this on docu

```
resolve

public javax.management.ObjectName[] resolve(Session session, javax.management.ObjectName scope, java.lang.String containmentPath)
     resolve the config object from its containment path.
Parameters:

     session - the seesion id. null may be supplied there a workspace will be created automatically and the change will be saved to repository.
     scope - the scope of search. scope may be a **cell, node or server**. we do cell wide search if scope is null.
     containmentPath - the containment path of config object.
```

Theres only Cell,Server and Node but no Cluster.....

I would like to know how to select Cluster Scopes.

Pls Help

Comment: we tried and failed to create JMSTopic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000532/not-able-to-create-jms-topic-programatically-in-websphere. Is there any specific settings we need to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WebSphere's Containment Path lingo, the keyword for clusters is `ServerCluster`, not `Cluster`.

Comment: perfect! It Works..... How did you know that?ServerCluster......
In all of the docu there call never a Cluster ServerCluster.....

Comment: Go to `wsadmin`, then `$AdminConfig types`, and look for the word "Cluster" there. That's IBM. :-)